# running a link through localhost on a live page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, httparty

I have an external program running a local API that is set up to play wav files when an endpoint is hit.

In my development environment, it works fine, but when I push to live environment it doesn't work any longer.

Am i missing something?

thanks!

**JqueryController**

```
  def playfile
    require 'json'
    HTTParty.get("http://192.168.1.161:5000/play/98")

    response = HTTParty.get("http://192.168.1.161:5000/play/#{params[:id]}")
    parsed = JSON.parse(response)
    @message = params[:message]
    Hint.first.update_attributes(message:@message)
    if parsed['success'] == true
      @success = "Success"
    else
      @success = "Failed"
    end
  end
```

The View

```
    =form_tag("/jquery/playfile", method: 'post', remote:true) do
      = label_tag 'hints on the tv!'
      = hidden_field_tag :id , 39
      =render 'layouts/play'
```

When I hit the endpoint .. googles inspector is showing a 'pending' request, which eventually dies, and returns an application error response (from heroku)

Im guessing it has something to do with not being allowed to hit a localhost address from a live site..is there a way to get around this?

Comment: If your production environment is not in your LAN, then it is quite obvious why it is not running. You will have to set up a NAT

Comment: Well, i just decided to hit the endpoint as a typical link and remove the get request...seemed to work :\

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot access your LAN from the internet (heroku).

If you make a GET on `http://192.168.1.161:5000/play/98`heroku will search in its own network..

Solution 1:

make a link (`<a href="http://192.168.1.161:5000/play/98"></a>`).
If you then hit that link from your LAN this would work. (you can use `redirect_back` if you want to redirect to back to the production site).

Solution 2:

make a tunnel from your `http://192.168.1.161:5000/play/98` device.
You can do this with [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) for example.
Then you would be able to make a GET request with HTTP Party from heroku. 
`HTTParty.get("http://<ngrok-hash>.ngrok.com/play/98")`

**NOTE: you need to have a running server on http://192.168.1.161:5000/play/98 for both solutions**